Coloring gt column after grouping the rows as columns
I am having trouble selecting the column after grouping it using gt. I have made some fake data to replicate what I am trying to do.
grade_level <- c("1st","1st","1st","1st", "2nd", "2nd", "2nd", "2nd", "3rd", "3rd", "3rd", "3rd",
           "4th","4th","4th","4th", "5th", "5th", "5th", "5th")
group <- c("District level girls", "District level boys", "State level girls", "State level boys",
           "District level girls", "District level boys", "State level girls", "State level boys",
           "District level girls", "District level boys", "State level girls", "State level boys",
           "District level girls", "District level boys", "State level girls", "State level boys",
           "District level girls", "District level boys", "State level girls", "State level boys")
nmbr_A <- sample(1:30, 20)
nmbr_B <- sample(1:30, 20)
nmbr_C <- sample(1:30, 20)
table_data <- cbind(grade_level, group, nmbr_A, nmbr_B, nmbr_C)

gt(table_data,
   rowname_col = "group",
   groupname_col = "grade_level") %>% 
  tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE) %>% 
  data_color(columns = 2,
             method = "factor",
             palette = c("#347f7f",  "#63b5b5", "#a97298", "#6c395c"))

I want to color the column that has the state or district-level girls or boys but after grouping I can't figure out how to select the column. It doesn't even have a name anymore (which I also can't figure out how to add a column name to it).

If you use columns = everything(), you'll see that that the grouping variables or stub is not colored. I'm fairly certain that you can't use that function to color the stub column.
You can use tab_style to color the stub though.
Since you can only assign one color in tab_style, you need to use it 4 times. I've used lapply to create the four color sets.
I set your colors to an independent object, so that I could call them in lapply.
Each iteration of lapply equates to one of the unique entries in group.
To collect the rows applicable, I used seq, starting with the current iteration of lapply, by: the number of unique labels (there are 4 here), and length.out: the number of unique of entries in grade_level—the other grouping variable (there are 5 here).
If you have any questions, please let me know.
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

gtt <- gt(table_data,
   rowname_col = "group",
   groupname_col = "grade_level") %>% 
   tab_options(row_group.as_column = TRUE) # without data_color()

clr = c("#347f7f",  "#63b5b5", "#a97298", "#6c395c")  # color list from question

invisible(lapply(1:length(unique(group)), function(j) { # for each unique entry in group
  gtt <<- gtt %>%                                       # add each tab_style to table
    tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = clr[j]),        # seq through colors
              locations = cells_stub(
                rows = seq(from = j,                    # start from current iteration
                           by = length(unique(group)),  # by unique entries
                           length.out = length(unique(grade_level)))) # by grade level
              )
}))
gtt  # let's see what we've got



